# render loop condition LIBGDX

Tags: java, loops, libgdx, render, conditional-statements

I am slowly learning `java/LIBGDX`, I have got the following method to change an image from black/white when clicked on, then I call on the `touchGem` method within render.

What I am having trouble wrapping my head around is putting a condition around calling this method within render to stop it rendering once the new black or white gem is created (as you can undoubtedly tell at the moment once clicked it renders the image over and over.)

```
public void touchGem() {

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    if (touchGemStatus1 < 1) {
        touchGem1 = new Image(touchGemTextureWhite);
        touchGem1.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        touchGem1.setSize(95, 95);
        touchGem1.setPosition(5, 0);
        touchGem1.addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                    int pointer, int button) {
                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                    int pointer, int button) {
                if (touchGemStatus1 < 1) {
                    touchGemStatus1 = touchGemStatus1 + 1;

                } else {
                    touchGemStatus1 = touchGemStatus1 - 1;
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        touchGem1 = new Image(touchGemTextureBlack);
        touchGem1.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        touchGem1.setSize(95, 95);
        touchGem1.setPosition(5, 0);
        touchGem1.addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                    int pointer, int button) {
                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                    int pointer, int button) {
                if (touchGemStatus1 < 1) {
                    touchGemStatus1 = touchGemStatus1 + 1;

                } else {
                    touchGemStatus1 = touchGemStatus1 - 1;

                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional info: "to stop it rendering" - rendering what? touchGem1? "new black or white gem" - what instances are they? "as you can undoubtedly tell" - no, we cannot. Please, provide your render() method. Do you want to switch touchGem1 color from black to white and vice versa once it is clicked?

Comment: 1) yea to stop rendering touchGem1, or rather to just render it once when clicked 2)touchGem1 either has a black or white texture which swaps when clicked, depending on if the int touchGemStatus is 1 or 0 (which clicking on it changes) 3) render method simply calls this method not much else. 4) yes thats exactly right, i want to swtich it between black to white and vice versa once clicked. The above code works, however it continually renders the new colour, ie when white and clicked on it renders the black image over and over until clicked again then it renders white over and over.

Answer (score 2):

if render() method calls only touchGem(), it doesn't render anything at all. To draw touchGem1, your render() method should look as following:

```
    @Override
public void render(float deltaTime) {

    deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    touchGem();

    batch.begin();
    stage.addActor(touchGem1);
    batch.end();
    stage.act(deltaTime);
    stage.draw();

}
```

Comment: edited your above comment to match my actual render method (with all the unrelated guff taken out.)

Comment: if you add actors in render() it will add actor each frame. It is unnecessary. You should removing old touchGem1 and adding new one to the Stage inside your touchGem() method.

Comment: surely at the moment it doesnt matter if its rendered every frame in the render method or rendered every frame in the touchGem1 method as touchGem1 is called in the render method? my original question was what condition i can put around calling the touchGem1 method within render to stop it rendering every frame, rather than just rendering the new colour once when clicked.

Comment: Surely, it **matters**.

Comment: will it not still repeatedly render if i move it within the touchGem1 method as there arnt any conditions which would stop it?